# Testing VSCode extensions - how to verify that decorations are set

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have an extension which adds text decorations at the end of some of the lines. I'd like to write a test which verifies that the text decorations are added and also to assert in the test that their value is correct.

```js
suite('Extension Tests', () => {
  test('Should work', async() => {
    const fixturePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'test', 'fixtures');
    const uri = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(fixturePath, 'a.js'));
    const document = await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(uri);
    await vscode.window.showTextDocument(document);
    window.activeTextEditor.getDecorations(); //???
  });
});
```

It seems that the `getDecorations` API is missing from editor. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Did you end up finding a way to access/verify decorations? I'm trying to unit test a similar feature.

Answer (score 1):

As of VSCode 1.37.1 (2019-08-30), the answer is **no**, there is no way to write an automated test for decorations using the [decorations extensions API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditorDecorationType).

There are automated tests of decorations in the vscode sources, particularly [modelDecorations.test.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/test/common/model/modelDecorations.test.ts), but they use private APIs.

Microsoft has an example extension that uses decorators, [decorator-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/decorator-sample), but it has no tests.

There are a few open issues related to this, although none directly addresses the inability to enumerate existing decorations:

- [50346](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/50346): Lacking decorations-related APIs (mainly about incremental update for better performance); closed as duplicate of:
- [585](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/585): Provide an API for advanced/semantic source highlighting
- [50415](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/50415): Missing API for knowing when an extension's decorations get trashed
- [54938](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/54938): Make decoration provider API public

Therefore I recommend filing a new issue.

---

2022-04-27: As noted in a comment, issue [136164: Provide Access to a TextEditors Decorations for Testing Purposes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136164) was filed on 2021-10-30.  It was then closed as unnecessary because you can test that your extension *calls* the extension API as intended.  I find this response inadequate because there's no way to test that the *effect* is as intended (for example, [TextEditor.setDecorations](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEdit) removes existing decorations that have the same type, and that's a subtle interaction that would only be revealed by examining the effects), but the issue is locked so yet another issue would have to be filed to raise an objection.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136164 i find that but idk how to use

Comment: @Mr.Trieu Added a link to that issue in my answer.  As for how to do what they are proposing (such as "// implement here a `set` method ..."), that could be the subject of a new question.